# how to get logged Twitter user's Detail using FHSTwitterEngine

Tags: ios, twitter-oauth, fhs-twitter-engine

oauth Login Twitter using FHSTwitterEngine. I want to fetch gender, email, username, birthday from twitter logged twitter account. Now, I got username only.

Comment: show your error log or what you have tried?

Comment: No Error Log

`UIViewController *loginController = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine]loginControllerWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
        NSLog(@"FHSTwitterEngine.sharedEngine.authenticatedUsername %@", FHSTwitterEngine.sharedEngine.authenticatedUsername);
        NSLog(@"FHSTwitterEngine.sharedEngine.authenticatedID %@", FHSTwitterEngine.sharedEngine.authenticatedID);
        

    }];
    
    [self presentViewController:loginController animated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: Does FHSTwitterEngine claim to be able to retrieve gender, email, and birthday? As far as I can tell, Twitter does not have an API to retrieve any of those. Take a look through the API docs to see if you can find something: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1

Answer (score 1):

Twitter API not allow to get the user email id (Protected). Other than this you can able   to fetch all the details using the following snippets,

//GET AUTHENTICATION ID ONLY IF LOGGED IN

```
 [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine] permanentlySetConsumerKey:twitterAPIKey
                                                     andSecret:twitterAPISecret];
 [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine] setDelegate:_signInVW];
 [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine] loadAccessToken];

//PASS YOUR TWITTER ID, TWITTER OAUTH TOKEN STR, TWITTER OAUTH TOKEN SECREAT STR

NSArray *timeLineAry = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine] getTimelineForUser:          [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine] authenticatedID] isID:YES count:1];
twitterID = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine] authenticatedID];
twitterOauthTokenStr = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine] accessToken].key;
twitterOauthTokenSecretStr = [[FHSTwitterEngine sharedEngine] accessToken].secret;

if (timeLineAry.count > 0) {
}
```

Using the timelinearray get the user screen name and post the data to the service, Finally you will get the user info.